# How does Amazon ec2-user get its sudo rights

Tags: amazon-ec2, sudo

I am looking for where the default Amazon AMI linux image sets up the privileges for the default `ec2-user` account.

After logging in with this account I can use sudo successfully.  Checking via the sudoers file, which I open by running visudo (with no other options) I see a few default settings and permissions for root ALL ALL

So ... Where is the permissions for ec2-user assigned?

I have not yet tried to add a new permission but ultimately I want to resign ec2-user for systems management tasks and use a non-full root user for administering the applications (stop and start mysql, httpd, edit apache's vhost files, and upload / edit web content under the web root)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's in `/etc/sudoers.d/cloud-init`.  I, too, delete it from my production systems as soon as I can.

It is included by virtue of the line

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

in the `/etc/sudoers` file.  Note that, as it says, that leading `#` isn't treated as a comment sign.  On some of my servers, it's **also** in `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users`; it may be safest to `userdel` the ec2-user user.

Comment: Yes it is.  Now why don't you fix your answer so that I can award you the credit?

Comment: What on _earth_ were the `sudo` devs thinking [with that #include syntax](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers) when the comment character is `#`?

Comment: @DaveGauer it's using the same syntax as a C preprocessor (`#include "file"` or `#include <stdio.h>`).  But yes, that's a bad choice for a config file.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is a file from /etc/sudoers.d/

```
From the master sudoers file, the very last part:
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Specifically the small bit which reads *# here does not mean a comment*

And then:

```
[root@webmaster ec2-user]# cd /etc/sudoers.d/
[root@webmaster sudoers.d]# ls -l
total 4
-r--r----- 1 root root 88 May  5 09:16 cloud-init
[root@webmaster sudoers.d]# grep ec2-user *
ec2-user ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
# User rules for ec2-user
ec2-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Voila.

Comment: Hi, I did this and now it's PWD protected.. how I remove?